# Big O notation for a function with x=>0

Tags: big-o

How should we represent function `f(x)=2x+1` with `x->0` with big O notation?

With reasons please.

(I think it should be written as `O(x)` as this function seems to grow faster than a constant function while one of my classmate think it should be written as `O(1)`.)

Comment: You're both correct. As x goes to 0 the value of your function is 0. And the function with all 0 is both part of the set of O(x) as well as O(1). Though usually you'd say O(1) since it's more accurate.

Comment: The value of my function is 1. So you are saying that it should be O(1)?

Comment: Sorry, obviously the value goes to 1. That's doesn't matter though. The O-notation is a set of functions. Both sets contain your function `(f(x) = 1)` so you're both right. Though, your friend is "more right".

Answer (score 4):

Big-O notation, in a nutshell, tells you the **performance** of your algorithm relative to the size of the input. I.e. you can use it to express something like *"on a small input, the algorithm is fast, but with double the input size the algorithm becomes 4 times slower..."*.

Your algorithm's performance is constant. It doesn't iterate or do anything which multiples with increased size of the input. Beyond implementation minutiae optimisation, it will always return a result in the **same amount of time.**

So it's O(1).

You cannot express the *value* of the result using Big-O.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Sorry, I am new to CS so would you mind if you explain to me what does "Beyond implementation minutiae optimisation" mean?

Comment: I mean, depending on what language you write this in and what architecture you run this on it ***may*** actually in practice take longer to multiple/add large numbers than small numbers. That depends on the details of how your architecture implements addition and multiplication. But this is not predictable and irrelevant for Big-O.